# Laravel Forge: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table already exists

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've gotten this error before but this time it's a bit different.

When I push an update to forge, Laravel Forge says it failed to deploy, but it deployed just fine. It just doesn't make any changes to the database structure due to this error:

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table
>   'job_posts'      already exists

When I run `php artisan migrate:status`, the job_posts table is the only one that shows as not ran, even though it clearly already has been ran.

Also dropping the existing table or anything that would delete existing records are out of the question as this change was made a few weeks back and users have already started using it.

Is there any way to solve this without removing existing records?

Comment: I would guess that there's an error in your migration. Often times a migration will successfully create a table, but fail in some other way. This will lead to the status of the migration not having been run, but the table existing. If it successfully works in local development, then compare the differences in database systems. Perhaps you've got a stricter configuration setting on the production database that is not present in your local dev environment.

Comment: The error also occurs on local, though.

Comment: OK, so that's helpful. Log in to the database, manually run `DROP TABLE job_posts;` and then re-run your migrations. This time, add the very very verbose option to get some more info in case the migration fails again. `php artisan -vvv migrate`

Comment: `php artisan -vvv migrate` migrated the table without error.

Comment: oh I hate non-reproducible errors. good luck!

Comment: Ah. I think it ran because I was testing `Schema::dropIfExists('job_posts');` before the migration. Though I'm trying to get rid of this error on Forge WITHOUT dropping the table as I want to keep the records.

Answer (score 1):

in your Migration you can simply use

```
if (!Schema::hasTable('job_posts')) {
  // your migrations
}
```

If it is false then run the migrations.

This way your records will not be deleted.

Hope this helps

Comment: Forge still gives me the same error, even after adding that.

Comment: @FelixMaxime I have updated the answer have a answer